# Numerical differences across threads (openMP on cygwin)

Tags: windows, multithreading, cygwin, fortran, openmp

I expect the following fortran code to generate the same results for all the threads. I am working on 32-bit windows 7 with an up-to-date cygwin. Gfortran version is 4.8.3

```
program strange
    use omp_lib
    implicit none


    real(kind=8) :: X(3)
    real(kind=8) :: R
    real(kind=8) :: R3

    !$omp parallel private(X,R,R3) default(none)

       X(1)=7.d0
       X(2)=5.3d0
       X(3)=0.d0

       R = dsqrt(X(1)**2 + X(2)**2 +X(3)**2)
       R3 = R*R*R

       write(*,*) "Thread ", omp_get_thread_num(), " results: ", R, R3


    !$omp end parallel

end program
```

On my machine I get

```
radg@pc_radg ~/morralla/terror
$ gfortran terror.f90 -fopenmp

radg@pc_radg ~/morralla/terror
$ ./a.exe
 Thread            1  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            0  results:    8.7800911157003370        676.85722410933886
 Thread            2  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            3  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
```

After running several times, I see that thread 0 always shows the same result, different from all the other threads. I have also observed that when changing the number of threads to be spawned (export OMP_NUM_THREADS=x), I still get the same wrong results from thread 0

When changing the optimization level, I get good results however

```
radg@pc_radg ~/morralla/terror
$ gfortran -O3 terror.f90 -fopenmp

radg@pc_radg ~/morralla/terror
$ ./a.exe
 Thread            0  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            1  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            3  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            2  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
```

The same program works properly on linux 64 bit machines (both 32 bit and 64 bit binaries). An example of such output

```
 Thread            3  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            0  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            1  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
 Thread            2  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
```

Any idea why can this be happening in my particular environment?

Comment: I have a similar setup and I could reproduce the problem. Any optimization will make all openMP threads to give the same result, but no optimization produces a different value for thread 0 only.

Comment: Why you use `dsqrt`? Generic `sqrt()` is with us since 1977. Also, Fortran 2008 introduced `hypot` and `norm2` but they are not that portable yet.

Comment: With the generic sqrt() I still get the same results

Comment: Of course, that was just a style remark.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered, that Fortran double precision typically has only [15 guaranteed significant digits](http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/Real+precision)?

```
Thread            1  results:    8.7800911157003387        676.85722410933931
Thread            0  results:    8.7800911157003370        676.85722410933886
Digits                      :    1 23456789012345--        123 456789012345--
```

In general this means, that everything after the 15th digit can not be trusted because of the intricacies of floating point operations.

You might want to read up on that [here](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/04/21/exceptional-floating-point/).

Especially [this](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/08/float-precisionfrom-zero-to-100-digits-2/) post in the series, concerning precision, explains, why you always get the same result on thread 0 as long as you don't recompile:

> ...
>   this guarantee is mostly straightforward (if you haven’t recompiled then you’ll get the same results) but nailing it down precisely is tricky.
>
> ...
>
> So the guarantee is really that the same machine code will produce the same results, as long as you don’t do something wacky.
>
> ...

Additionally [this](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/06/26/doubles-are-not-floats-so-dont-compare-them/) post of the series, concerning doubles might interest you, too.